# Eclipse IDE project "data master"

Tags: eclipse

Next to some projects in my Eclipse IDE workspace, it's written `data master`.
What does it mean?
Can you point towards some documentation?

Comment: Possibly information from whatever version control system you are using (Git, SVN, ...) Look in the "Version Control (Team)" menus in the Preferences for configuration information on that.